# Why do these two calls to Apply return different results?

Tags: list-manipulation, evaluation, core-language, pure-function

In the following example, why do these two calls to `Apply` return different results?

```
list = {"a", "b"};
Apply[f, list]
Apply[f[#] &, list]
```

> f[a, b]

> f[a]

In contrast, when using `Map` (which is a different function from `Apply`), these two calls return results identical to each other:

```
list = {"a", "b"};
Map[f, list]
Map[f[#] &, list]
```

> {f["a"], f["b"]}

> {f["a"], f["b"]}

Comment: Keep in mind `#` is short for `Slot[1]`, which represents (only) the first argument. Also remember `Trace` or `TracePrint`: On simple code, such as `Apply[f, list] // Trace` and `Apply[f[#] &, list] // Trace`, the `Trace` gives a nice sequence that shows how an expression is evaluated.  (`TracePrint` shows more and is therefore both more complete and more complicated to follow.)

Comment: Another difference, not exhibited in this question, is that if `f` has `Attributes`, then `f[##] &` does not. In practice, this matters most when `f` has a `Hold*` attribute such as `HoldAll`. [A better question might be what are the differences between `f` and `f[#] &`.]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Oh, I was also surprised by the differenxe, but I have an explanation for it: By using `f[#]&`, you explicitly say that the functions shall only use the first argument. Use `##` otherwise.

```
Apply[f[#] &, list]
Apply[f[##] &, list]

f["a"]

f["a", "b"]
```